# Does algebraic factorization imply the same 0 factoring pattern for non-polynomial expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose one has $e^{f(x)}(g(x)-e^{h(x)}) = 0.$ Can it then be inferred that either $e^{f(x)}=0$ or $g(x) - e^{h(x)} = 0$ makes this statement true, similar to how $x(1-x^2)$ would yield that $x=0$ or $x\pm 1$ are solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. At least one of those must be zero, so assume the other is nonzero and divide both sides by it. (This is perfectly legal since it is nonzero.) Then the other factor is equal to zero.

For instance, assume $e^{f(x)} \ne 0$. Then you can divide both sides by it to conclude that $g(x) = e^{h(x)}$. Similarly, you can do the same if you assume $g(x) - e^{h(x)} \ne 0$. Divide both sides by it and one concludes $e^{f(x)} = 0$.

Comment: Alright thank you. Btw I'm surprised you don't have a blender profile.

Answer (score 4):

$e^{f(x)} >0$ no matter what $f(x)$ is. Hence we can cancel $e^{f(x)} $ and conclude that we must have $g(x)=e^{h(x)} >0$.

Comment: This is definitely incorrect. If $f(x) = \ln(x)$ then one solution is $x=0.$

Comment: In your example $f(0)$ is not defined. You are supposed to work within the real line and not bring in infinite values.  @CheeseMongoose

Comment: Exactly, $f(0)$ isn't defined, so you shouldn't go about making assumptions that it can't exist. $\pm \infty$ are part of the real line, they make it topologically open.